# Perl didn't match backslashes

Tags: regex, perl, backslash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text replacement with backslash in a variable in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969220/text-replacement-with-backslash-in-a-variable-in-perl)

Why this code didn't work?

```
my $foo = '\aa\bb';
my $bar = '\aa\bb\ee\ss.txt';

say $bar =~ m/^$foo.*$/ ? 'OK' : 'BAD';
```

With forward slashes is all OK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969220/text-replacement-with-backslash-in-a-variable-in-perl?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Before putting your regex there, you should probably use **[`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)** first.

```
my $foo = quotemeta('\aa\bb');
```

The backslashes when put into the regex, carry **special** meaning. `quotemeta` will escape them, in order to match them literally.

Answer (score 4):

You have to quote special char,

use this:

```
say $bar =~ m/^\Q$foo\E.*$/ ? 'OK' : 'BAD';
             __^    __^
```

Have a look at [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: Shouldn't it have a closing `\E`?

Comment: @Cthulhu: Yes it should. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
/^\aa\bb.*$/
```

- `\a` matches the "alarm" character.
- `\b` matches a word boundary.

You want to generate a pattern that matches a given string. For that, you can use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $pat = quotemeta($foo);
/^$pat.*$/
```

`quotemeta` can also be called using `\Q..\E`.

```
/^\Q$pat\E.*$/
```